# Sorting a data.frame in R maintaining row names

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a data.frame with daily percentage returns of several Managers, I want to sort the data.frame so that to have, for example the best 5 performers and the worst 5 performers.

I found the function `sort(x)` or `rev(sort(x))` but they do not maintain rownames and I need them in order to check the names of Managers.

Any tips?

Comment: Somewhat confusingly, we typically use `order` to sort things like data frames in R.

Answer (score 4):

I found this in some other website and it worked for me:

If you select a single column, then the default is to drop the data.frame 
property.To suppress this behavior you can set drop = FALSE:

```
df.sort <- df[order(df[,"x"]), , drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but none of the Q&A I've seen on SO have dealt with single column data frames.  @eddi 's answer doesnt work when you only have one column:

```
df.2col <- data.frame(a = c(4:1), b = c(1:4), row.names = paste0('blah', c(1:4)))

print(df.2col[order(df$a),])
```

results in a nice sorted data frame:

```
      a b
blah4 1 4
blah3 2 3
blah2 3 2
blah1 4 1
```

BUT, with a single column,

```
df.1col <- data.frame(a = c(4:1), row.names = paste0('blah', c(1:4)))

print(df.1col[order(df$a),])
```

the row names are trashed:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

the kludgy solution I've had to resort to was sorting both data and rows:

```
df.sorted<-data.frame(a=df.1col$a[order(df.1col$a)],row.names=row.names(df.1col)[order(df.1col$a)])

print(df.sorted)
```

The desired result:

```
      a
blah4 1
blah3 2
blah2 3
blah1 4
```

If there is a better way to do this, I would appreciate any guidance

Comment: I have the same problem sorting a single column and my kludgy solution was to add a second column e.g. `df.1col$one <- 1` and that worked.

Answer (score 2):

You want `order`:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(4:1), b = c(1:4), row.names = paste0('blah', c(1:4)))
df
#      a b
#blah1 4 1
#blah2 3 2
#blah3 2 3
#blah4 1 4

df[order(df$a),]
#      a b
#blah4 1 4
#blah3 2 3
#blah2 3 2
#blah1 4 1
```